# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. IsolatedStorage Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0

I am a beginner to C# and Visual Studio. I have Built a Silverlight application to get Custom Parameters in the player to play the video in out of browser.

The code for running the application out of browser is given below:

```
        // When running outside the browser, retrieve initParams from isolated storage.
        if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file =
                IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())

            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
                "initParams.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, file))
            {
                // The serializer requires a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.
                DataContractSerializer serializer =
                    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<String, String>));
                initParams = (Dictionary<String, String>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, save initParams to isolated storage.
        else
        {
            initParams = e.InitParams;

            using (IsolatedStorageFile file =
                IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
                "initParams.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create, file))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer =
                    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, initParams);
            }
        }
```

And I get the error, the operation is not permitted. IsolatedStorage Exception in the code

```
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file =
                IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())

            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
                "initParams.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, file))
```

The Error Message in Visual Studio is

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not
>   permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   IsolatedStorageFile isf)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, IsolatedStorageFile isf)    at
>   testplayer.App.LoadInitParams(StartupEventArgs e)    at
>   testplayer.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
>   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex,
>   Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)    at
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr
>   unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex,
>   String eventName, UInt32 flags)

Can Anyone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance